# the mouse scroll change the selected index of combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

There is a combo box on a form.

The Code when the form is loaded.

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combo.Items.Clear();
    combo.Items.Add("01");
    combo.Items.Add("02");
    combo.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

If I scroll the mouse wheel that it will change the index of the combobox.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Please try rephrase your question. Do you want to select a different item on the combobox?

Comment: I have edited your question based on my understanding, if that is not what you meant, you can edit your own question.

Comment: Seems like the combo box has the focus. Then it is supposed behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the `Tab Order` of your controls.Set all tab-order of your controls.

Go form design.Click View in menu bar,then choose Tab Order.

Your combo tab order must not be the first one.

If u want to change from coding,

`combo.TabIndex=10;`

The problem is your `combo` is selected at form start.So you scroll mouse wheel,it's selected index changed.

Answer (score 1):

Change selected element on mouse scroll is default behaviour of focused combobox. If you want to suppress this, you can use PreFilterMessage function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285919/can-the-mouse-scroll-wheel-always-affect-a-panel).